# Fields don't grey-out when disabled in certain browsers

Tags: html

I use many different fields for my website such as radio list, text area, checkbox, textbox, dropdown, date, etc.Sometimes these fields are set at disabled.

Functionally, this means their values cannot be edited. This works correctly on all browsers.

Aesthetically, it means they should be greyed out somehow. When using Internet Explorer, all fields are shown as greyed out upon being disabled. However, in Firefox and Chrome, only radio buttons, checkboxes, and dropdowns are clearly greyed out. All other fields look the same, just as if they are still enabled.

I would appreciate any help in figuring out how to make all fields grey out in all browsers when being disabled.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the background colour of the fields to grey? `el.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';`

Answer (score 4):

You can use css

```
input[disabled]
{
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}
```